# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have a problem about creating bean with name appUserRepository defined in com.example.taskcrud.Repository.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.taskcrud.appuser.AppUser

It took me the whole day to fix that problem. Could anyone help me please.

This is my link GitHub project: https://github.com/LongNguyenVu24/IT4883Q_Project_Group5-BE

This is my error

```
2023-05-24T18:36:31.090+07:00  WARN 11816 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserService' defined in file [T:\At-school\backend-workmanage\IT4883Q_Project_Group5-BE\taskcrud\taskcrud\target\classes\com\example\taskcrud\appuser\AppUserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository' defined in com.example.taskcrud.Repository.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.taskcrud.appuser.AppUser
2023-05-24T18:36:31.091+07:00  INFO 11816 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-24T18:36:31.094+07:00  INFO 11816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-24T18:36:31.114+07:00  INFO 11816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-05-24T18:36:31.117+07:00  INFO 11816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-24T18:36:31.144+07:00  INFO 11816 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-24T18:36:31.200+07:00 ERROR 11816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserService' defined in file [T:\At-school\backend-workmanage\IT4883Q_Project_Group5-BE\taskcrud\taskcrud\target\classes\com\example\taskcrud\appuser\AppUserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository' defined in com.example.taskcrud.Repository.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.taskcrud.appuser.AppUser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.example.taskcrud.TaskCrudApplication.main(TaskCrudApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository' defined in com.example.taskcrud.Repository.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.taskcrud.appuser.AppUser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.taskcrud.appuser.AppUser
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my AppUserRepository class

```
@Repository
//đảm bảo rằng trong quá trình thực thi phương thức, không có thay đổi nào được thực hiện trên cơ sở dữ liệu.
// Nếu bất kỳ thay đổi nào được thực hiện, Spring sẽ ném ra một ngoại lệ.
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface AppUserRepository  extends JpaRepository<AppUser,Long> {
    Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE AppUser a " +
            "SET a.enabled = TRUE WHERE a.email = ?1")
    int enableAppUser(String email);

}
```

this it's my appUserService class

```
package com.example.taskcrud.appuser;


import com.example.taskcrud.Repository.AppUserRepository;
import com.example.taskcrud.registration.token.ConfirmationToken;
import com.example.taskcrud.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenService;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

//@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND = "user with email %s not found";
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    private ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private  final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    public AppUserService(AppUserRepository appUserRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService) {
        this.appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.confirmationTokenService=confirmationTokenService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND,email)));
    }

    public String signUpUser(AppUser appUser){
        boolean userExists = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail()).isPresent();
        boolean isConfirmAt = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail()).isPresent();
        if(userExists)
        {
//

//            todo:when the user exists  but user has not confirm, he must permit the user to confirm email again
            throw  new IllegalStateException("Email is exists ");
        }

        String encodedpw = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(appUser.getPassword());
        appUser.setPassword(encodedpw);
        appUserRepository.save(appUser);
//        todo; send confirmation token

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(
                token,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15),
                appUser
        );
        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);
        return token;


    }

    public int enableAppUser(String email){
        return appUserRepository.enableAppUser(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that AppUser is not a JPA managed type. This class needs to fulfill some requirements to be a JPA managed entity. Share the code of AppUser. Maybe somebody can help you find the deficit. Or - even better - check any online docu and find out what is missing.

Comment: I have shared the link of my GitHub prj above .Can you help me please

Comment: I have imported your entity and repository and run - no errors. But I can see in the stacktrace the class com.example.taskcrud.Repository.AppUserRepository It is not on git. At least not in the package Repository. Maybe you should just synchronize your local project with GitHub? Your are not up-to-date. Hope it helps. I will not be able to invest more time...